# IOError: HTTP session not yet started when running [gem install bundler]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I tried to install bundler by using `gem install bundler`, however, I got the following error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - IOError: HTTP session not yet started (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Also, I tried to install webpacker by using `gem install webpacker`, and I got the following error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'webpacker' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Can anyone help me fix these two issues? I have searched on Google, but I didn't see efficient answers.

I installed ruby-2.7.2 using rvm on M1 chip macOS Big Sur 11.4.

Thanks Thanks Thanks!!!

Comment: ok, my update on this: I quit the installation process, and restart it (doing this multiple times) and now ```gem install bundler``` and ```gem install rails``` works for me (didn't change anything, worked for no reason), but ```gem install webpacker``` still no response.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not accessing rubygems.org. It can be an authorization issue on your end. Make sure that api.rubygems.org is correctly authorized.

You can test it by running `curl https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz`